# Is it possible to connect to an MDB file present in Zip file?

Tags: java, database, ms-access

I have a java application to read MDB files. Now I have to change the application to read the MDB files a zip file. So I was trying to connect through the below code but got no success,

```
LOG.debug("Filename : " + filename);
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb);DBQ="
                    + filename + ";";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "");
            Statement s = conn.createStatement();
```

where filename is the mdb file name present in the zip file. So need help in how to go about to achieve this. Or is there no way to connect to an MDB file which is present in a zip file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There no way to connect to an MDB file which is present in a zip file.  You will have to extract it to a temporary file first, and then connect to it.